# Labeling with time_out difference between Sicstus 4.2.3 and 4.3.0

Tags: clpfd, sicstus-prolog

In Sicstus 4.2.3 it is possible to do like this:

```
| ?- X in 0..2, labeling( [minimize(X), time_out(1000, Lr)],[X] ). 
X = 0,
Lr = success ? yes
| ?-
```

If you do the same in Sicstus 4.3.0 you get:

```
| ?- X in 0..2, labeling( [minimize(X), time_out(1000, Lr)],[X] ). 
X = 0 ? yes
| ?-
```

What happened to `Lr`  in 4.3.0?

And how do you know if the solution you get in 4.3.0 is the optimal solution or if the solution is a non-optimal solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug of course.  Lr should be bound to 'success'.  With Lr left unbound, there is no telling whether the solution is optimal.

Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Upvoting is the way to say thank you on SO. See [help] -> [Tour]